# Saving vectorization layer with functional Tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've been using a `tf.keras.Sequential` model recently for some text classification with just one output, and after the model has been trained I can export it like this:

```
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        layers.Embedding(vocabulary_size + 1, embedding_dim),
        layers.Dropout(0.2),
        layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
        layers.Dropout(0.2),
        layers.Dense(len(classes))]
    )

    print("Compiling model")

    model.compile(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
        metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy']
    )

    print("Training model")

    model.fit(
        train_ds,
        validation_data=val_ds,
        epochs=epochs,
        class_weight=class_weights)

    loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_ds)

    print("Exporting model")

    export_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        vectorize_layer,
        model,
        layers.Activation('sigmoid')
    ])

    export_model.compile(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
        metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy']
    )

    export_model.save('models/' + save_file_name)
```

... which saves my vectorization layer in the model, and makes it super easy to consume using something like Tensorflow Serving.

For reference, the vectorization part further up looks like this:

```
    vectorize_layer = layers.TextVectorization(
        output_mode='int',
        output_sequence_length=sequence_length)
    
    def vectorize_text(text, label):
        text = tf.expand_dims(text, -1)
        return vectorize_layer(text), label

    # Make a text-only dataset (without labels), then call adapt
    train_text = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: x)
    vectorize_layer.adapt(train_text)
    vocabulary_size = len(vectorize_layer.get_vocabulary())
```

I recently started working on a similar model but with multiple outputs, so I had to switch to a functional model:

```
    input_1 = KerasInput(shape=(250,))
    x = Embedding(input_dim=vocabulary_size + 1, output_dim=embedding_dim, input_length=250)(input_1)
    x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.2)(x)

    category_output = Dense(len(classes), name="category")(x)
    age_output = Dense(2, name="age")(x)
    gender_output = Dense(3, name="gender")(x)

    model = Model(inputs=input_1, outputs=[category_output, age_output, gender_output])

    print("Compiling model")

    model.compile(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
        metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy']
    )

    print("Training model")

    model.fit(
        train_ds,
        validation_data=val_ds,
        epochs=epochs,
        class_weight=class_weights)

    print("Exporting model")

    export_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        vectorize_layer,
        model,
        layers.Activation('sigmoid')
    ])

    export_model.compile(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
        metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy']
    )
```

The model trains wonderfully, but of course the last two parts don't work, because it's not a Sequential Model any more. But I can't seem to find any way to create a functional model from my trained model with the vectorization layer added.

Anyone know how I can convert `model` to `export_model` with `vectorization_layer` attached?

Thanks so much for your help!